# overfloating tabularx{}

Tags: xetex, tabularx

I have a tabularx{} table as below, but cant tell why it is floating. Many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}      
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!ht]
    \footnotesize
    %\scriptsize
    \centering 
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{ll*{1}{l} }
        \toprule
        %& Variable name & Definition \\ 
        Variable name & Definition \\ 
        \midrule
        \textit{\text{independent variables}} \\ 
        \cline{1-1} \\
        $x_1$  Gender & \textit{\text{male = 1, female = 0}}  \\
        $x_2$  Marital Status & \textit{\text{married/cohabited = 1, otherwise = 0 }}   \\
        $x_3$  Age &  household's age in years \\
        
        $x_4$  Employed & \textit{\text{employed = 1, otherwise = 0 }}  \\
        $x_5$  Education & \textit{\text{high school or higher = 1, otherwise = 0 }}   \\
        $x_6$  Party &  \textit{\text{affiliation with Chinese Communist Party (CCP) = 1, otherwise = 0 }}  \\
        $x_7$  HR &     \textit{\text{urban = 1, rural = 0 }}  \\
        $x_8$  Region & \textit{\text{west, east, and center.}}  \\
        $x_9$  Income & household's income in Chinese Renminbi (CNY).  \\
        $x_{10}$ Net-worth & The value of financial and non-financial assets minus liabilities in Chinese Renminbi (CNY). \\ 
        $x_{11}$ NW-HE & Net-worth minus home equity in Chinese Renminbi (CNY). \\ 
        $x_{12}$ Liquid Assets &  Cash and other easily cash-able assets in Chinese Renminbi (CNY). \\ 
        
        \midrule
        \textit{\text{dependent variables}} \\ % & \underline{\textit{Does your household currently need loan? (n= 1458) }} \\  
        \cline{1-1} \\
        $y_1$  Access to loan & \textit{\text{Access to loan = 1}} if the household head has any type of loan (e.g formal, informal, and/or both),
        otherwise \textit{\text{Access to loan = 0}}. \\
        
        $y_2$ Access to loan type &   if the household head has formal, informal, or both loans \textit{\text{Access to loan type}} is equal to 1, 2, 3 respectively, otherwise     \textit{\text{Access to loan type = 0}} which indicates the household head has not have any type of loan.   \\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Definitions of the independent variables. \textit{Note: In equations $x_{10}$, $x_{11}$, and $x_{12}$ were use interchangeability. }} 
    \label{tab:def.of.varss}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the only purpose of the `table` environment is to specify that the content floats.

Comment: unrelated to that, every tabularx must have an X column and your only has `l` so tabularx can not work

Comment: You declare a total of 3 `l` type columns, but as fas ar I can tell, two columns (as in`\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{lX}`) would be sufficient. Also, what's the purpose of `\text` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue, I think, is that you've failed to insert `&` alignment markers in most columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} llR @{}}
    \toprule
        %& Variable name & Definition \\ 
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Variable} & Definition \\ 
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\uline{\textit{independent variables}}} \\\addlinespace 
        $x_1$ & Gender & \textit{male${} = 1$, female${} = 0$}  \\
        $x_2$ & Marital Status & \textit{married\slash cohabited${} = 1$, otherwise${} = 0$ }   \\
        $x_3$ & Age &  household's age, in years. \\
        
        $x_4$ & Employed & \textit{employed${} = 1$, otherwise${} = 0$ }  \\
        $x_5$ & Education & \textit{high school or higher${} = 1$, otherwise${} = 0$ }   \\
        $x_6$ & Party &  \textit{affiliation with Chinese Communist Party (CCP)${} = 1$, otherwise${} = 0$ }  \\
        $x_7$ & HR &     \textit{urban${} = 1$, rural${} = 0$ }  \\
        $x_8$ & Region & \textit{west, east, \textup{and} center.}  \\
        $x_9$ & Income & household's income, in CNY. \\
        $x_{10}$ & Net-worth & The value of financial and non-financial assets minus liabilities, in CNY.\\ 
        $x_{11}$ & NW-HE & Net-worth minus home equity, in CNY.\\ 
        $x_{12}$ & Liquid Assets &  Cash and other easily cash-able assets, in CNY.\\ \\
        
        
        \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\uline{\textit{dependent variables}}} \\\addlinespace 
        % & \underline{\textit{Does your household currently need loan? (n= 1458) }} \\  
        $y_1$ & Access to loan & \textit{Access to loan${} = 1$} if the household head has any type of loan (e.g formal, informal, and/or both); otherwise \textit{Access to loan${} = 0$}. \\
        
        $y_2$ & Access to loan type & if the household head has formal, informal, or both loans \textit{Access to loan type} is equal to 1, 2, 3, respectively; otherwise \textit{Access to loan type${} =\allowbreak 0$}, which indicates the household head does not have any type of loan.   \\

    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize Note: In equations $x_{10}$, $x_{11}$, and $x_{12}$ were use interchangeability. } \\
    \end{tabularx}
    
    \caption{Definitions of the independent variables.} 
    \label{tab:def.of.varss}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: love where you add the Note as well <3